# Defer in script tag not work as script evaluates before HTML is parsed

Tags: javascript, html, seo, pagespeed

```
<script defer src="js\js_W2mJqnHnL8R-M2XrnaNYgPkWXECHurpgXtp2OSv8apY.js"></script>
```

I have put the above script in head tag.
[image]

I consider this a render blocking resource as the lcp loads after this

I don't want this to happen and want it to be evaluated later after the html is parsed.

What to do?

Comment: How exactly have you come to the conclusion that the script is blocking the HTML? Unless you're using a strange broken browser, it isn't. What does the script do?

Comment: I thought it comes before LCP(Largest Contentful Paint).That is why?

Comment: No, the deferred scripts run after the DOM is parsed but before DOMContentLoaded is fired.

Comment: So how do I eliminate resource render delay?

Comment: Well without knowing anything about what this script does, if it's computationally heavy you could put it in a web worker.

Comment: Where can I learn more about web workers and how to implement them?

Comment: [At the Mozilla MDN website.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API)